# how to map in hibernate

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate.
I am facing problem at the time of mapping
in my table no primary key is there . but two not null values are there 
how i can represent them in hibernate
thanks in advance

my table structure is like this

```
Field                   Type         Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment
----------------------  -----------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  -------
ApplicationId           bigint(20)   (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references         
ApplicationName         varchar(32)  latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references         
IsTimeSubsciptionValid  tinyint(4)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
IsUserCountValid        tinyint(4)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
MaxUserCount            int(11)      (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
IsMaxAccessCountValid   tinyint(4)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
MaxAccessCount          bigint(20)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
IsParentingAvailable    tinyint(4)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         
TimePeriodAllowed       bigint(20)   (NULL)             YES             0                        select,insert,update,references         


Table Query.

Table             Create Table                                           
----------------  -------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationTable  CREATE TABLE `ApplicationTable` (                      
                    `ApplicationId` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
                    `ApplicationName` varchar(32) default NULL,          
                    `IsTimeSubsciptionValid` tinyint(4) default '0',     
                    `IsUserCountValid` tinyint(4) default '0',           
                    `MaxUserCount` int(11) default '0',                  
                    `IsMaxAccessCountValid` tinyint(4) default '0',      
                    `MaxAccessCount` bigint(20) default '0',             
                    `IsParentingAvailable` tinyint(4) default '0',       
                    `TimePeriodAllowed` bigint(20) default '0',          
                    PRIMARY KEY  (`ApplicationId`)                       
                  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found out that Hibernate requires a primary key, even if there isn't one on the table.  Any unique key will do (and I believe there's a way to use ROWID as well).

It looks like you want something like this:

```
    <id name="ApplicationId" column="APPLICATIONID">
    </id>
```

but you say there are 2 not null values you want to map?  I'm a little unclear as to what the problem is.

Comment: Apparently you don't care that much?  Wish someone would answer some of my questions.